# Access existing MySql database with ruby (paths?)

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have an existing mysql db used by a rails app. I want to create a Ruby script to run to perform a weekly maintenance task on the database. My first line is:
    `require 'mysql'`
I have tried various 'paths' to point there but get an error message like:

```
1:in `require': no such file to load
```

I have:

> code at:   \ruby\sites\somepgm
>   mysql at:  \ruby\lib\gems\1.8\gems\mysql-2.8.1-x86-mswin32

How do i get them to be nice to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'
```

Comment: This works! I figure I should learn Ruby separate from Rails to understand the whole thing better, so thats the purpose of this exercise. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: sometimes your gemrc file will load rubygems for you as well, so it isn't always clear if you have to do that or not but usually if you get a gem load error, its the first check.